# Difference between hikari and datasource configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

My question is regarding spring datasource configuration. I don't understand difference between this two configuration types in application.yml file. If you suggest me any source for reading or answer I will be grateful to you.

spring:
datasource:
hikari:
jdbc-url:
username:
password:

spring:
datasource:
url:
username:
password:

Answer (score 0):

Connection pooling is a technique used to improve performance in applications with dynamic database-driven content. [Read Details](https://dzone.com/articles/database-connection-pooling-in-java-with-hikaricp)

HikariCP is a very fast lightweight Java connection pool. The API and overall codebase are relatively small (a good thing) and highly optimized. [HikariCP Dtails](https://dzone.com/articles/database-connection-pooling-in-java-with-hikaricp)

Useful Resource:

1. [JPA-Hibernate-Hikaricp-Config](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/jpa-hibernate-hikaricp-config/)